# Grails how methods created automatically/dynamically for domain class?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria, grails-domain-class

I am working on Grails framework. I am wondering that how grails domain class method are dynamic generate for each domain class of grails application like

**count,
countBy,
createCriteria,
delete,
discard,
errors,
executeQuery,
executeUpdate,
exists,
fetchMode,
find,
findAll,
findAllBy,
findAllWhere,
findBy,
findOrCreateBy,
findOrCreateWhere,
findOrSaveBy,
findOrSaveWhere,
findWhere,
first,
get,
getAll,
getDirtyPropertyNames,
getPersistentValue,
hasErrors,
hasMany,
hasOne,
ident,
instanceOf,
isAttached,
isDirty,
last,
list,
listOrderBy,
load,
lock,
merge,
read,
refresh,
save,
validate,
where,
withCriteria,
withNewSession,
withSession,
withTransaction**

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 3.x no metaprogramming is used to extend the domain classes. I think they use AST instead

Comment: "In Grails 3.x no metaprogramming is used to extend the domain classes." - That isn't entirely true.  We still use runtime metaprogramming for things like dynamic finders which cannot be rigged up at compile time.  A lot of other things that used to be done with runtime metaprogramming have been replaced with trait based solutions or custom AST transformations, but runtime metaprogramming is still used in Grails 3.

Comment: Is there a way to add methods to all domains

Comment: there are lots of ways to do it: inheritance, traits, meta-programming like in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Grails, the methods mentioned in the question are defined in a trait that Grails automatically adds to your Groovy domain classes.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/9c66dbfdec33311d768fc230e704150d213e87ab/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.groovy.  For example, the `count()` method is defined at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/9c66dbfdec33311d768fc230e704150d213e87ab/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.groovy#L620.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is done through [metaprogramming](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html), you can add methods and properties to any class dynamically.

```
SomeClass.metaClass.newMethod  = {-> // do my stuff here }
```

You should use this conservatively to avoid collisions with other libraries trying to add the same method to the same class.

Hope this helps.